# How to run a SQL script in Intersystems Cache?

Tags: intersystems-cache

I have a script in a file (mysqlscript.sql) that is basically a bunch of inserts/updates/deletes separated by GO statements

```
insert into ....
GO
update .....
GO
```

How do I run this script?

Comment: Be careful about differences between SQL dialects. You can encounter some problems even if you find out how to run the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use $system.SQL.[ImportDir()](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20121/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25SYSTEM.SQL#ImportDir)
And of course, you can read your file and execute each sql-query in your programm.

Comment: this is not available in my version (2009)

Answer (score 0):

The tool [Caché Monitor](http://www.cachemonitor.de) use **GO** as statement separator and connects to InterSystems Caché. With this tool you can execute your script.